# How to convert byte array to audio file?

Tags: audio, voip, rtp, sdp, jain-sip

I have written a program that gets SIP packets in real time from the network and I want to use the SDP information embedded in the packets to capture the audio conversation from two VOIP soft phones.

Once I retrieve the binary data from the RTP protocol how should I go about converting it into a sound file?

c++ preferred.

Comment: Hi new Contributor! Nice to meet ya! SDP is an Session Description , this means it describes the type of data you are looking at, for Audio data it is better to look at RTP or SRTP (Real-time Transport Protocol /  Secure Real-time Transport Protocol) . So from SDP you can get how to read data from RTP , such as network encryption. To help you more i would need an https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That's correct, an example would help a lot. Regarding your question, it depends on the type of audio data you are receiving, SDP should describe the type and other information like sample rate, sample size, etc. Once you determine the type of audio, you need to follow RTP specification to form a frame out of RTP packets.

Comment: hello and thank you for the kind responses. i will provide some actual code as an example as soon as i can. the class that parses the sip packets coming from the network is quite large tho’ so i will try to summarise: it extracts all the information from the packets using regexpressions so getting the required rtp info would be no problem. i plan on feeding the rtp ports into a sniffer (i am using the libtins library). this sniffer will then provide me with a byte buffer that should contain the audio exchange, at least that is what i think, so i would need to turn that into an audio file.

Comment: provided i can already parse the information in the sdp packets and get the sample rate, size and other parameters (not exactly sure which, my signal processing skills are kind of dumb), how would i go about converting that information along with the byte buffer into something i can listen to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Adrian and welcome,

You are right, we cannot directly put the **RTP** payloads in a file concatenated one after another and then reading this file as an audio file, let's say a `".wav"`.

The missing part that you are looking for is a piece of code that re-assemble, decode and play-out the rtp flow of packets into voice samples; for the sake of simplicity, consider the wellknown `G.711` or `PCM` codec because all SIP phone support this codec.
You need to implement a `Playout buffer` (logically an infinite buffer but a ring buffer with wrap around is ok).

The packet itself contains audio data in small payload of 20ms duration. Each chunks of audio data is preceded with a RTP header, which indicates the type of encoding (This is related to the SDP information and you have a good understanding of that part).

For each packet:

1. Decode the 8-bits values into 16 bits samples at the right rate usually 8,000 times per second for `G.711`;
2. Compute from the RTP header the play-out point, it is the index in the play-out buffer array. 
   *Take into account jitter and re-ordering based on RTP timestamp*
3. Write the samples into a `.wav` or play it to an audio device.

From a pragmatical point of view, you may do that in several ways:

- You collect all the UDP/RTP packets in a capture file and use [`wireshark`](https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP) to do the hard work;
- Use an existing tool, like [playSIP A command-line SIP session recorder](http://live555.com/playSIP/);
- Grab a library or write existing code for that purpose but that is not an easy task. You can think about handling packet loss for instance.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. good day to you sir

Comment: You are welcome, do not forget to accept the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is only from the audio recording point of view

( .wav file - audio codec used in the call is a-law /u-law)

This approach you can take without coding .

Use Wireshark to capture the network packets ( in pcap file)

Wireshark-> Telephony -> Stream Analysis

In Stream Analysis windows -> Save ( drop down menu - select Forward/reverse stream Audio)

Save it in .raw file format.

Open the .raw file format in Audacity and convert it to .wav file.

I hope it helps you.